# "Er wuchs ein verschlossenes Kind" & "Er ist ein verschlossener Mensch gewachsen"?

Tags: word-usage, verb-choice

Are these sentences correct? I know, that it is possible to say "Er war ein verschlossener Mensch" and "Er ist ein verschlossener Mensch geworden". But can we say in the same way with the verb "wachsen"?

Answer (score 9):

No, these sentences are not correct, as *wachsen* cannot be used like that.

The closest form that I can think of (and that probably matches what you want to express) is *zu ... heranwachsen*:

- Er wuchs zu einem verschlossenen Kind heran.
- Er ist zu einem verschlossenen Menschen herangewachsen.

Answer (score 3):

You mean like in *to grow to be smth.*? There's no directly translatable expression in German I know.

But if you want to emphasize the development/progress, add such a adverbial expression like:

```
im Laufe der Zeit; mit der Zeit; über die Zeit; allmählich
```

if you really want to use the verb *wachsen*, you can use *heranwachsen* and say:

```
Er wuchs (allmählich/mit der Zeit) zu einem verschlossenen Mann heran.
```

BUT: Saying that, you're describing the timespan from child to adult.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't say that. "Wachsen" has nothing to do with "verschlossener Mensch". "Wachsen" means to grow, not to become ("werden").